# Error in imports of Angular Material only in build

Tags: angular, angular-material

I migrated a project that was in version 7 of the angular with angular material 7 also to version 10. It works fine, except that when I'm going to do the Build, it shows me an error in imports. I can't say for sure if it is in imports, but everything indicates that it is. The error that presents me is this:

- If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, the verify that it is part of this module

Which means that in the build, he is not finding the Angular Material modules.

Another detail that I don't know if it's related, is that to run the project I'm using the node command line --max_old_space, because the project is too big and exceeds the memory limit

This for any module of the angular material. The strangest thing is that only in Build this happens, in the ng serves, normal

Comment: Did you enable `Ivy`? https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Comment: No, I'm going to do this test. I didn't know about that kind of compilation. I come back here to tell you what happened